# Are these two expressions equivalent? Checking by hand or Mathematica

Tags: summation, closed-form, mathematica

Are the following two expressions equivalent?

**Expression 1:** $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{x^k}{k!}\sum_{L=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(k+L)!}{L!}y^L$$

**Expression 2:** $$\sum_{L=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{y^L}{L!}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{(k+L)!}{k!}x^k$$

WolframAlpha doesn't think so, but I am not convinced:

**Expression 1:** http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn-1%7D%5Cdfrac%7Bx%5Ek%7D%7Bk!%7D%5Csum_%7BL%3D0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cdfrac%7B(k%2BL)!%7D%7BL!%7Dy%5EL

**Expression 2:** http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7BL%3D0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cdfrac%7By%5EL%7D%7BL!%7D%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn-1%7D%5Cdfrac%7B(k%2BL)!%7D%7Bk!%7Dx%5Ek

How can I check this directly in Mathematica?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{x^k\over k!}\sum_{L=0}^{\infty}{(k+L)!\over L!}y^L
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{L=0}^{\infty}{x^k\over k!}{(k+L)!\over L!}y^L
=\sum_{L=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{x^k\over k!}{(k+L)!\over L!}y^L
=\sum_{L=0}^{\infty}{y^L\over L!}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{(k+L)!\over k!}x^k$$

Comment: What version of Mma?  In 11.0, Mma cannot confirm the second equality.

Comment: No version of Mma used or needed. It's just interchanging two independent summations. $$\sum_{k=a}^b\sum_{L=c}^df(k,L)=\sum_{L=c}^d\sum_{k=a}^bf(k,L)$$

Comment: Of course, but the OP said: "How can I check this directly in Mathematica?"  And the interesting piece of that emerges when you exchange the order of summation.  (Or equivalently, when one attempts to simplify the second of the two expressions.)

Comment: @Alan, I went by the title, which includes the phrase, "Checking by hand". I regret that I am not sufficiently fluent in Mathematica to contribute anything to that part of the discussion. Perhaps ask at mathematica.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 1):

I have no knowledge of Mathematica, but as an aside I'll point out that the first version allows easy calculation of a closed form:

$$\begin{align*}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{x^k}{k!}\sum_{L\ge 0}\frac{(k+L)!}{L!}y^L&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{x^k}{k!}\sum_{L\ge 0}\binom{k+L}kk!y^L\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k\sum_{L\ge 0}\binom{k+L}ky^L\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{x^k}{(1-y)^{k+1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{1-y}\cdot\frac{\frac{x^n}{(1-y)^n}-1}{\frac{x}{1-y}-1}\\
&=\frac{x^n-(1-y)^n}{(x+y-1)(1-y)^n}\;.
\end{align*}$$

For the second I see nothing better than reversing the order of summation.